# How not to print repeated character in "for loop"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
from string import ascii_letters
from random import choice

lowercase_list = [letter for letter in ascii_letters[:26]]
uppercase_list = [letter for letter in ascii_letters[26:]]

raw_str = ""
for i in range(10):
  rand_str = choice(lowercase_list)
  raw_str += rand_str

print(raw_str)

for l in raw_str:
  str_count = raw_str.count(l)
  print(f'{l} repeated {str_count} time(s) in string.')
```

For example:

trbtcgbbgn

"t" repeated 2 times. That's why Python prints 2 times that "t" repeated 2 times.
If same object repeats many times. Python shouldn't print the number of repition for same object.
Which codes should I add my codes for this?

Comment: FYI, `lowercase_list = ascii_letters[:26]` will suffice.

Comment: or just `from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase` ;)

Comment: Do you want to print how often a character occurs, or do you want to print each unique character only once? Are you aware of [``random.sample``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Counter` to do your counting:

```
from collections import Counter

for c, count in Counter(raw_str).items():
    print(f'{c} repeated {count} time(s) in string.')
```

By iterating over the `Counter` instance, you will visit each character exactly once.

---

(You also don't need an explicit loop to generate `raw_str`:

```
raw_str = ''.join(random.choices(lowercase_list, k=10))
```

.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `set` like so:

```
raw_str = "trbtcgbbgn"
for l in set(raw_str):    #<-- use set() here
  str_count = raw_str.count(l)
  print(f'{l} repeated {str_count} time(s) in string.')
#c repeated 1 time(s) in string.
#n repeated 1 time(s) in string.
#t repeated 2 time(s) in string.
#b repeated 3 time(s) in string.
#g repeated 2 time(s) in string.
#r repeated 1 time(s) in string.
```

Comment: Calling `count` repeatedly is inefficient. Each call iterates over the entire list, ignoring most of what it sees.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I usually solve the questions with the least amount of edits just to be easier to understand to the OP

Comment: FYI, I didn't downvote your answer and I see it's a possible solution

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't think it was you. It's clear we both interpreted the question the same way, and arrive at the same result.

Comment: Thanks all of you guys. I didn't expect you to answer so fast. Using sets really makes sense. :) :)

Comment: If you don't mind, could you mark this answer as the [accepted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png), please?